# With $s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n n \bmod k$, can be justified that $\forall\epsilon>0$ let us $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(n-1)}{\epsilon+s(n)}=1?$

Tags: limits, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, arithmetic-functions, experimental-mathematics

Denoting as

$$s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n n \bmod k$$ **the sum of remainders function** (each remainder is defined as in the euclidean division of integers $n\geq 1$ and $k$). See [1] for example.

**For examples**  $s(1)=0$ and
 $$s(6)=0+6\bmod4+6\bmod5+0=2+1=3.$$

After some **computational experiments** I am interesting in

> **Question.** Can you prove or refute (too are welcome heuristics) that $\forall\epsilon>0$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(n-1)}{\epsilon+s(n)}=1?$$
>   Similarly that $\forall\epsilon>0$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(n)}{\epsilon+s(n-1)}=1?$$
>   **Thanks in advance**, it seems curious, and I believe that previous is a strong condition in the sense that its proof could be easy, or well in the sense that find a counterexample could be easy (I am refering to the presence of such $\epsilon$).

**I don't know if previous exercises are in the literature.**

There are formulas involving this function (see [1] for example) with the **sum of divisors function** $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$, that holds for each integer $n>1$

$$\sigma(n)+s(n)=s(n-1)+2n-1,$$

and **a companion formula** that can be deduced inductively from previous (see too in [1]).

Well my experiements aren't the bests, neither I have enough *resolution to see the limit*, but **there is a difference** when I plot $\frac{s(n)}{s(n-1)}$ ($n\geq 5$) or $\frac{\sigma(n)}{\sigma(n-1)}$ or $\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(n-1)}$, where this last is Euler's totient function.

**References:**

[1] Math Overflow, How to calculate the sum of remainders of N? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195325/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-remainders-of-n

I've read the notes from two authors Spivey and Cross.

Comment: I'm not sure that the presence of $\epsilon$, has importance if you can compute the limit as $1$. Thank.s

Comment: It seems that $s(n)$ isn't erratic. The arithmetic functions as $\sigma(n)$ are more erratic, but I don't know how answer previous questions without use the graph of $s(n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have well understood, you put $n=qk+r(n,k)$ with $0\leq r(n,k)<k$, and then $\displaystyle s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n r(n,k)$. For $k\geq 1$, you have $\displaystyle q=[\frac{n}{k}]$ ($[x]$ is the integer $m$ such that $m\leq x<m+1$). Hence your sum is
$$s(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k[\frac{n}{k}])=n^2-n^2(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}[\frac{n}{k}])$$

Put $\displaystyle f(x)=x[\frac{1}{x}]$ for $0<x\leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $$ R_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}[\frac{n}{k}]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n f(\frac{k}{n})$$ is a Riemann sum relative to $[0,1]$, and the function $f$. This function is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$ (as $f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$, and that the function is clearly Riemann-integrable on $[a,1]$ for every $a\in ]0,1[$). It is easy to compute the integral:

$$\int_0^1f(t)dt=\sum_{k\geq 1}\int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k}f(t)dt=\sum_{k\geq 1}u_k$$
with
$$u_k=\int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k}ktdt=\frac{k}{2}(\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2})=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})+\frac{1}{2(k+1)^2}$$

Hence
$$\sum_{k\geq 1} u_k=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Now you have $\displaystyle s(n)\sim n^2(1-\frac{\pi^2}{12})$ and it is easy to finish.

Comment: Very thanks much @Kelenner, I've understand all details. Thanks, truly.

Comment: If I there are no mistakes in my computations, combining Aguirre's answer $O(\frac{1}{n})+\frac{\sigma(n)}{s(n-1)}=\frac{2n-1}{s(n-1)}$ with Gronswall's theorem (that states $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sigma(n)/n\log\log n=e^\gamma$, labelling $O(s(n-1)/(n^2\log\log n))=\text{error term}=\epsilon$, I believe that $\limsup |\epsilon|=e^\gamma$. And in the other hand I believe that Kelenner's answer implies $\limsup |\epsilon|\sim C\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2\log\log n}=0$. I say this to show that truly I am interesting in this, and say another time thanks @Kelenner

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that
$$
s(n)=\Bigl\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\Bigr\rfloor\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}j+\sum_{j=1}^{n\bmod k}j.
$$
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}s(n)=\infty$ and $s(n)-s(n-1)<k$. It follows that
$$
\frac{s(n)}{s(n-1)}=1+O\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Very thanks much @JuliánAguirre your proof is more short than Kelenner's proof, but I've choosen Kelenner's proof since is more instructive, and more useful to me currently, to see more easy facts in game. Very thanks much. Muchas gracias, de verdad.

Comment: I will try follow all statements in your proof.

Comment: If I there are no mistakes in my computations, combining Aguirre's answer $O(\frac{1}{n})+\frac{\sigma(n)}{s(n-1)}=\frac{2n-1}{s(n-1)}$ with Gronswall's theorem (that states $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sigma(n)/n\log\log n=e^\gamma$, labelling $O(s(n-1)/(n^2\log\log n))=\text{error term}=\epsilon$, I believe that $\limsup |\epsilon|=e^\gamma$. And in the other hand I believe that Kelenner's answer implies $\limsup |\epsilon|\sim C\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2\log\log n}=0$. I say this to show that truly I am interesting in this, and say another time thanks @JuliánAguirre