# Exploring the Dirichlet series of the sum of remainder function

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series

I wolud like to learn and understand more some basic facts about **Dirichlet series**, for wich I want explore the following function, that is called the **sum of remainders function**, A004125 as [Sloane's sequence](https://oeis.org/).
$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \text{nmod k}.$$

> **Question 1.** Can you explore the **abscise of absolute convergence** $\sigma_a$ for the Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{S(n)}{n^s}?$$

Facts that I thought are, the first that it is known that this function is related with the **sum of divisor function** $\sigma(m)=\sum_{d\mid m}m$, by 
$$\sigma(n)+S(n)=S(n-1)+2n-1,$$
which holds for each $n>1$. Thus I can think in the diference $|f(n)-f(n-1)|$ and perhaps use the **triangle inequalities** or the knowdlegde that we have about the sum of divisor function. Too if we multiply by $n^{-s}$ we can get the Dirichlet series for $\sigma>2$ for the sum of divisor function and $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(s-1)$, and perhaps from here you know how work with $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{S(n)}{n^s}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{S(n)}{(n+1)^s}$.

Following Apostol's book, *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* (now page 226), if we can get a bound $|S(n)|$, I would like write the bound for the tails $|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{S(n)}{n^s}|$ as is stated in **Lemma 1**, for a $\sigma\geq c\geq \sigma_a$, which is a direct application of such lemma, but I ask if one time that you know previous bound for $|S(n)|$, then

> **Question 2.** Can you get an upper bound for $$|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{S(n)}{n^s}|?$$ 
>   And, can you conjecture or deduce the abscise corresponding with a  **half-plane for which the Dirichlet series** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{S(n)}{n^s}$ **is never zero**?

**Thanks.** I would like to ask more about these pages, for example the question concerning the limit uniformly to S(1)=0, but I assume that I am learning slowly.

**Update:** The remarks that were deduced in comments:

If we're only looking at $k \geq n/2$, then $n \bmod k = (n-k)$, and summing that gives approximately $n^2/8$.

So the series converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re} s > 3$.

Comment: I don't know if such exercise are in the literature.

Comment: If you can find an $\alpha$ so that $S(n) \in \Theta(n^{\alpha})$, determining the abscissa of absolute convergence is easy.

Comment: Well, I don't know how get $O(n^\alpha)$, but you can tell me how if we assume that $S(n)\in O(n^\alpha)$, how find the abscissa of absolute convergence, so I know for the next time. Thanks @DanielFischer

Comment: If $\lvert a_n\rvert \leqslant C\cdot n^{\alpha}$, then absolute convergence of $\sum \frac{n^{\alpha}}{n^s}$ - which happens if and only if $\operatorname{Re} s > \alpha + 1$ implies the absolute convergence of $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s}.$$ Conversely, if $c\cdot n^{\beta} \leqslant a_n$, the absolute convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ implies the absolute convergence of $\sum \frac{n^{\beta}}{n^s}$. So if $a_n \in \Theta(n^{\alpha})$, the abscissa of absolute convergence is $\alpha + 1$.

Comment: Very thanks much for the deduction and write the proposition @DanielFischer

Comment: For your coefficients $S(n)$, clearly $S(n) \leqslant \sum_{k = 1}^n k$, so you have $S(n) \in O(n^2)$. Can you also find a lower bound for $S(n)$ of the form $c\cdot n^{\alpha}$? What's the largest $\alpha$ you can reach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35941/discussion-between-user243301-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: @ user243301 : how do you prove $\sigma(n) = S(n-1) - S(n)  + 2n+1$ ? and it is not so helpful as $\sum_n n^{-s} \sum_{k \le n} \sigma(k)$ is not related to $\zeta(s)$, only $\int_1^\infty x^{-s-1} \sum_{k \le x} \sigma(k) dx = \zeta(s)^2/s$ is. so $\int_1^\infty S(x) x^{-s}dx$ is directly linked to $\zeta(s)$, but not $\sum_n n^{-s} S(n)$ (the difference between the two being $\mathcal{O}(1)$)

Comment: Sorry by last message, the aricle of Cross, A note on almost perfect numbers (MATHEMATICS MAGAZINE 47 · SEPTEMBER 1974) , which shows a proof refers that the theorem (it is cited as Dickson[1, page 312]) was proved by **Lucas**. I don't have an access to James T. Cross article. Now I will read your message. Very thanks much @1952009

Comment: But it is possible find a equation between $\zeta(s)$ and the previous Dirichlect series for $S(n)$, denoting this last as $F_S(s)$, it is possible find it from the [1st equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663216/a-question-about-a-weighted-average-mean-related-with-the-sum-of-remainders-func), combining with your $\int_1^\infty x^{-s-1} \sum_{k \le x} \sigma(k) dx = \zeta(s)^2/s$? If it is possible for what $s$ holds? Is the same $\Re(s)$>3? Thanks and sorry if you can answer these questions @user1952009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for question 1**: Following (I copy these) the comments written below myself question, by the user, for our coefficients $S(n)$, we have clearly 
$$S(n)\leq \sum_{k=1}^n k,$$
so we have $S(n)\in O(n^2)$. We can also find a lower bound for  $S(n)$ of the form $c\cdot n^{\alpha}$, when we answer the question *what is the largest $\alpha$ that we can reach?*  Well, if we're only looking at $k \geq n/2$, then $n \bmod k = (n-k)$, and summing (for example with Gauss identity) that gives approximately $n^2/8$. **By calculus**, see comments about the computations of the abscissa of absolute convergence, since we show that $S(n) \in \Theta(n^{\alpha})$, then we can say that **the abscissa of absolute convergence** is $\alpha+1=3$ .So the series converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re} s > 3$.

**My answer for question 2**: Then by **Lemma 1** (page 226 of Apostol's book) for $\sigma\geq c>3$ and $N>\geq 1$
$$|\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{S(n)}{n^s}|\leq N^{-(\sigma-c)}C\cdot\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{c-2}}.$$

I know that I can write (from the asymptotic formulas derived using **Euler's summation**, stated as Theorem 3.2 in page 55)

$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{c-2}}=O(N^{3-c}).$$

I don't say nothing more best than this. I don't try compute approximations for these tails to do a comparision.

**If you can improve my answer your are welcome.**

Comment: I add the reference (I say the answers that gave the users to a past question) since their [answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545993/with-sn-sum-k-1n-n-bmod-k-can-be-justified-that-forall-epsilon0-le) could be useful